# Pegar o registro mais recente de uma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como faço para trazer o resultado mais recente de uma consulta.

````
Registro da consulta.
|       DATAHORAFINAL    |USUARIO|FASEATUAL|
|------------------------|-------|---------|
|2022-02-09 11:49:17.750 |2083   |  3      |

```SQL
SELECT PO.DATAHORAFINAL,
PO.USUARIO,
PO.FASEATUAL
FROM PEG AS P
INNER JOIN PEG_OCORRENCIA AS PO
ON P.HANDLE = PO.PEG
WHERE P.PEG = 19100033
AND (PO.FASEATUAL = 6 OR PO.FASEATUAL = 3);

|       DATAHORAFINAL    |USUARIO|FASEATUAL|
|------------------------|-------|---------|
|2022-02-09 11:49:07.593 |2083   |  6      |
|2022-02-09 11:49:17.750 |2083   |  3      |
````

Comment: No título da pergunta você diz "mais recente", no corpo "mais antigo"; está contraditório,, a qual dos dois você realmente se refere?

Answer (score 0):

Aplique o **MAX()** no campo que precisa ver o **maior valor** ou **MIN(seu campo)** para ver o **menor valor**, mas não esqueça de adicionar os campos que deseja visualizar no GROUP BY no fim da consulta.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(PO.DATAHORAFINAL),
    PO.USUARIO,
    PO.FASEATUAL
FROM PEG AS P
INNER JOIN PEG_OCORRENCIA AS PO ON P.HANDLE = PO.PEG 
WHERE P.PEG = 19100033
    AND (PO.FASEATUAL = 6 OR PO.FASEATUAL = 3)
GROUP BY PO.USUARIO, PO.FASEATUAL;
```